# Javascript setFullYear

Tags: javascript, date, object

```
var currentDate=new Date();
currentDate.setFullYear(2011);
alert(currentDate);
```

This works, it sets the year to 2011 as expected.

```
alert((new Date()).setFullYear(2011));
```

This one doesn't work.

Any idea why? Am I misunderstanding the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

When you write `alert((new Date()).setFullYear(2011))`, you are calling `setFullYear`, and passing its return value to `alert`.

`setFullYear` returns a timestamp, not the original `Date` object.
Therefore, it doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: setFullYear() returns a timestamp.